# Knowing the number of arguments passed to a method in java

Tags: java

Lets say that I have a java method:

```
public void setStuff(String... stuff)
```

Is there a easy way for me to know the number of strings passed, without using a loop to test for it?

I basically want to know how many Strings are passed, so I can simply make an array of that size out of it.

Comment: `stuff` is an array. Use `stuff.length`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`stuff` is simply an array. So calling `stuff.length` should give the length

Comment: Thanks for the help, I didn't know that it was simply an array.